# How to create a database in Visual Studio using SQL authentication?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I want to be able to package my program as an exe-file basically.

To do so I need a connection string just connecting to a local DB file using username/password.

If I could turn DB security OFF that would also work.

Every time I create a new data connection or DB file it is automatically created with Windows authentication turned on and I am apparently not allowed to change this through "modify connection".

I am using VS 2011, but I assume the process is pretty standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB security cannot be turned off, its built in.